# how to make proper alignment at the beginnig and at the end in gvim?

Tags: vim

When i am in writing python code,there are continious lines need to be proper alignment.

1)proper alignment at the beginnig

From 20 to 24 line,how to make every beginning character display at the 4th column?

2)proper alignment at the end

From 20 to 23 line,how to make every ending character `\` (the continious symbol)display at the 78th column?

Let me make the problem more concrete.
the initial status is

```
pattern=[['CompanySurvey','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/CompanySurvey.aspx?code=sz%s'],  \  
           ['ShareholderResearch','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/ShareholderResearch.aspx?code=sz%s'],  \  
             ['BonusFinancing','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/BonusFinancing.aspx?code=sz%s'],           \  
                 ['FinanceAnalysis','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz%s'],     \  
         ['CapitalStockStructure','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/CapitalStockStructure.aspx?code=sz%s']]
```

i want to make the 5 lines left and right  alignment .

1.with method of Ingo Karkat

:2,5left9

it get the display

```
pattern=[['CompanySurvey','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/CompanySurvey.aspx?code=sz%s'],  \  
             ['ShareholderResearch','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/ShareholderResearch.aspx?code=sz%s'],  \  
             ['BonusFinancing','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/BonusFinancing.aspx?code=sz%s'],           \  
             ['FinanceAnalysis','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz%s'],     \  
             ['CapitalStockStructure','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/CapitalStockStructure.aspx?code=sz%s']]
```

2.with method of FDinoff

```
:%s/.$/\=repeat(' ',107-len(getline('.'))).submatch(0)
```

It get the output.

```
pattern=[['CompanySurvey','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/CompanySurvey.aspx?code=sz%s'],                \
         ['ShareholderResearch','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/ShareholderResearch.aspx?code=sz%s'],    \
         ['BonusFinancing','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/BonusFinancing.aspx?code=sz%s'],              \
         ['FinanceAnalysis','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz%s'],            \
         ['CapitalStockStructure','http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/CapitalStockStructure.aspx?code=sz%s'] ]
```

It is so long for `:%s/.$/\=repeat(' ',107-len(getline('.'))).submatch(0)` to do that ,can anyone make it simple?

Comment: how to write for replace and insert?

Comment: Before/after sample, please.

Comment: What do you want to do if there is more than 78 characters? And what is the beginning character? Does whitespace count as a character?

Comment: You could write a custom function which you could then turn into a command if you are planning of using this regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I'm not sure if there is an easier way.

This moves the last character to the 78th column by adding the correct number of space characters.

```
:%s/.$/\=repeat(' ',78-len(getline('.'))).submatch(0)
```

This moves shifts the line so that the first non whitespace character appears in column 4. Where the number of whitespace characters is the columns - 1

```
:%s/\s*\(\S.*\)/\=repeat(' ',3).submatch(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first use case, `:20,24left 4` should be enough.

Have a look at my [AlignFromCursor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155). It offers mappings (and commands) to align (left or right) to a certain column. This will help with aligning the `\` line continuation (with the cursor placed on or before it) via `78<Leader>ri`.